# Print content of a div inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript

I have a foreach loop in php. Now I need to print the content of a div for each record separately what I have now is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printContent(div_id) {
        var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById("<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>");
        var html = '<html><head>' +
            '</head><body style="background:#ffffff;">' + DocumentContainer.innerHTML +
            '</body></html>';

        var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow", "width=1000,height=1000,top=0,left=0,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
        WindowObject.document.writeln(html);
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        //WindowObject.close();
        document.getElementById('print_link').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Then I have the following div:

```
<div id="brief_print" style="margin-left: 15px">
.
.
.
.
.
</div>
```

And perhaps a link like this:

```
<a class="glow" style="text-decoration: underline;" href="javascript:printContent('<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>')"id='print_link'>Open in new window for printing</a>
```

My problem is that when I hit the link I don't get anything in return. Please tell me where I'm wrong.
Thanks

The entire codes:

```
<?php
foreach($allroutes as $route)
{
?>
<tr>
<td onclick="$('#details_<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>').toggle('slow')">P</td>
<td style="padding:5px 10px" ALIGN="center"><?php echo $route->depicao;?></td>
<td style="padding:5px 10px" ALIGN="center"><?php echo $route->arricao;?></td>
<td style="padding:5px 10px" ALIGN="center"><?php echo $route->aircraft; ?></td>
<td style="padding:5px 10px"ALIGN="center"><?php echo $route->distance;?></td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="14"><div align="center">
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="details_<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>" style="display:none">
<tr><th style="padding:5px 10px"><div align="center">Flight Details</div></th></tr>
<tr><td>
<section>
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['newwindow']))
{
?>
<a class="glow" style="text-decoration: underline;" href="javascript:printContent('<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>')"id='print_link'>Open in new window for printing</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printContent(div_id)
{
var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById("<?php echo $route->flightnum;?>");
var html = '<html><head>'+'</head><body style="background:#ffffff;">'+ DocumentContainer.innerHTML+ '</body></html>';
var WindowObject = window.open("",  "PrintWindow","width=1000,height=1000,top=0,left=0,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
WindowObject.document.writeln(html);
WindowObject.document.close();
WindowObject.focus();
WindowObject.print();
//WindowObject.close();
document.getElementById('print_link').style.display='block';
}
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<div id="brief_print" style="margin-left: 15px">

<pre>
<b>Departing</b>    : <?php echo $schedule->depname ?>
<b>Arriving</b>     : <?php echo $schedule->arrname ?> 
<b>Equipment</b>    : <?php echo $schedule->fullname;?>
<b>Alternate</b>    : <?php echo $alternate1; ?> 
<b>Alternate</b>    : <?php echo $alternate2; ?> 
<b>Alternate</b>    : <?php echo $alternate3; ?> 

</pre>
</div>
</section>
</td></tr>
</table>    
</div>
<?php 
 }
?>
```

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong and doing a mixup between PhP (server-side) and javascript (client-side). You probably don't need that function in javascript and can do everything in PhP

Comment: `"when I hit the link I don't get anything in return"` - Can you be more specific?  What's actually rendering to the browser?  What does your PHP code produce client-side?  In what specific way is it failing?

Comment: PHP executes on the server side. So before your page is ever transmitted to the client, PHP is done processing. Javascript is executed on the client side. So you cannot interact with PHP via JS without making a new call to the server with something like AJAX. Take a look at the View Source output in your browser. You won't see any PHP there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Okay the php code is returning records from database by using a foreach() loop and inside the loop I want to be able to print the content of a table but it will be different every time. If I choose the id to be a name like "details" only the first record will be passed to the function for all other records is the same. !!!!:(

Comment: @ParvizKhorraminejad: So choose an id that's unique to each row. Show more of your PHP code.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the entire codes.

Comment: @Travesty3, I can't add a unique tag for each record since there are more than 3000 records.

Comment: @ParvizKhorraminejad: Why not? Something like `details-0`, `details-1`, ..., `details-3000`, etc.

Comment: @Travesty3, Not a chance!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some big problems with your code. You don't seem to understand what is happening when and where. Let me try to explain.

When a client goes to a website, their browser sends a request for the page to your hosting server. Your host server executes the PHP code, producing the source code for the page to be sent to the client's browser. So the page is not sent back to the client's browser until after PHP has **completely finished executing**. No JavaScript code has executed at this point.

Once the page is sent to the browser (and PHP is **done**), that's when JavaScript takes over. JavaScript executes on the client-side.

So, once you understand this, you'll realize that you obviously cannot call PHP from JavaScript without making a new request to the server.

---

Try opening your page in a browser and view the source. You will see that you are defining the JS function `printContent()` once for every loop iteration. You are also missing closing tags for your second `<tr>` and `<td>` tags (add an extra `</td></tr>` after your last `</div>`). Perhaps you'll realize all the other problems when you view the source to see what your PHP code is producing.